# Metrizable Groups and Symmetric Neighborhoods

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, topological-groups

Show that in a metrizable group, every neighborhood $U$ of the neutral element $e$ contains a neighborhood $V \ni e $ such that $V\cdot V^{-1} \subset U$, where $V\cdot V^{-1} = \{x\cdot y^{-1}; x\in V, y\in V\}.$ A neighborhood $V \ni e $ is said to be $\textbf{symmetric}$ when $V = V^{-1}$ , where $V^{-1}= \{x^{-1}; x\in V\}$. And show that every neighborhood of $e$ contains a symmetric neighborhood .

I do not know how to get this issue if they can give you some tips to solve it would be very grateful.

Comment: Groups Metrizable is a metric space G, provided with a group structure such that operations $m: G\times G \rightarrow G$, $m(x,y)= x\cdot y$ and $f:G \rightarrow G$, $f(x)= x^{-1}$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that whenever $V$ is a neighborhood of the identity element $e$, so is the set $V^{-1} = \{x^{-1} : x \in V \}$ a neighborhood of $e$, then it is natural to consider the intersection $U = V \cap V^{-1}$ of both neighborhoods.

Now try to prove that $U$ is a **symmetric** neighborhood of $e$, as required.  That is,

(a) Show $U$ is a neighborhood of $e$.

(b) Show $x \in U$ implies $x^{-1} \in U$.

I'd point out that this is only using the topology of a group (via continuity of the inverse operation), and so it is more general than only concerning *metrizable* groups.

Comment: I still can not understand exactly how to resolve this issue, I can not see the things that matter.

Comment: Do you understand that I'm claiming $U = V \cap V^{-1}$ is a symmetric neighborhood, given that $V$ is a neighborhood of $e$?  Apply the definition, as you gave in the Question.

Comment: Exactly, it is now clear what you mean. Sorry for my slowness in understanding.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I wanted you to see the idea for yourself, and it will often happen that I don't find the right words on the first try.